# Dealing with poorly formatted times

Tags: php, mysql, sql, formatting

My company has a page on its website containing a text input field for start times. Now they need me to convert the form to use selects for the times instead. Because, until now, the times inserted in the database came from a text input, there is no time formatting convention shared by the rows in the database.

For example:

```
mysql> SELECT classtime FROM classes LIMIT 10;
+-----------+
| classtime |
+-----------+
| 3PM       |
| 9:30am    |
| 9:00am    |
| 9:30am    |
| 3:00pm    |
| 10:00am   |
| 3:00      |
| 10:30     |
| 11:30     |
| 9         |
+-----------+
10 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

These are just 10 of about 45,000 rows.

I am trying to write processing logic that will display the original data along with the new restricted-format data. Obviously, I need to write a conditional to differentiate the two, but I can't seem to think of a good way to tackle it. Since the new data will be converted using `strtotime()` before being inserted into the database, my original thought was to write a conditional that checks if the data retrieved from the database is numeric or not, then display accordingly.

The only problem is that many of the rows already contain time fields with numerically formatted times:

```
mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM classes WHERE classtime REGEXP '^[0-9]*$';

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      273 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

As you can see, this method will not work. Anyone have any suggestions? Thank in advance.

**EDIT (additional info):**
A lot of the fields also contain values like: "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM", or "3 PM to 4 PM", etc.

Comment: So what is the new format to look like? You have shown basically four different type of current formats, as these all you are dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtotime() function in PHP to convert most of them.

```
$new_time = date('h:i', strtotime($old_time));
```

Of course, the 'h:i' could be any format you'd like.

Comment: I'm not sure that this will work... A lot of the fields contain things like: "12:00 PM - 1:00 PM", or "3 PM to 4 PM", etc.

Comment: I would run it and insert the new time in another field.  Then query to see how many of them return 1969-12-31.  If it's a reasonable number, you may can do some regex on those separately.  The fact that most of them already have numeric entries isn't an issue, as strtotime will still convert them.  I don't know if you'll get them all in one swoop, but I'd try to get as many as possible the easy way and then see where you're at.

Comment: Thanks for your help. If you don't mind my asking, why "1969-12-31"?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP guy and was looking at this from a database perspective. In your query you can format all the times you listed pretty easy but the ranges you mentioned in the comment above would need to be cleaned up or split prior.

```
DECLARE @BadFormatTimes TABLE
(
  badTime VARCHAR(20)
)

INSERT INTO @BadFormatTimes (badTime) VALUES ('3PM')
INSERT INTO @BadFormatTimes (badTime) VALUES ('9:30am')
INSERT INTO @BadFormatTimes (badTime) VALUES ('9:00am')
INSERT INTO @BadFormatTimes (badTime) VALUES ('9:30am')
INSERT INTO @BadFormatTimes (badTime) VALUES ('3:00pm')
INSERT INTO @BadFormatTimes (badTime) VALUES ('10:00am')
INSERT INTO @BadFormatTimes (badTime) VALUES ('3:00')
INSERT INTO @BadFormatTimes (badTime) VALUES ('10:30')
INSERT INTO @BadFormatTimes (badTime) VALUES ('11:30')
INSERT INTO @BadFormatTimes (badTime) VALUES ('9')
INSERT INTO @BadFormatTimes (badTime) VALUES ('12:00 PM - 1:00 PM') -- This will fail
INSERT INTO @BadFormatTimes (badTime) VALUES ('3 PM to 4 PM') -- This will fail 

-- Run update script to clean up time ranges or split and format

SELECT 
 badTime 'Bad Time',
 CAST(badTime AS time(0)) AS 'Clean Time' 
FROM @BadFormatTimes
```